# Add number when button was clicked

Tags: c#, events, button

I made an application which calculate the total price, I want that when the button is clicked, it add 1 to the quantity, but it only add 1 and when I click the button again, It doesn't add, Is there a way to loop a button?

here is my sample code

```
int intclicks;

private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    intclicks++;
    int qty = 1;
    {
        if (intclicks > 0)
        {
            int totalqty;
            totalqty = qty + 1;
            textBox3.Text = totalqty.ToString();
            totalPrice();
        }
    }

}
```

the `totalPrice();` sets display the total price in another `textBox`, 
thanks.

Comment: I changed the `loop` tag to `events` there is no loop here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign `qty =1` in the beginning of the event, so, yes it starts from the beginning.

There is too much missing here, but it seems like you can use:

```
int qty = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
...
```

Comment: I made it a default `qty` value, so if button is not clicked, it will be 1

Answer (score 0):

When you click a button in a GUI-program, it fires the event once. Looping in the ClickEvent seems not very useful, as it would be blocking the main-thread and so your UI would freeze.
You could start a thread which loops in the background. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for threading.
Please explain further what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have set int qty= 1 before your loop start and in your if condition you are checking if (intclicks > 0). So when you first time click the button it will check if (intclicks > 0) but as you have set qty = 1 the condition will be false and it wont go in the if condition. So change if condition to

```
if (intclicks >= 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is a little out here for what (I believe) you are trying to do, why not try.

```
int intclicks;
int totalqty;

private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    intclicks++;
    if (intclicks > 0)
    {
        totalqty++
        textBox3.Text = totalqty.ToString();
        totalPrice();
        intclicks = 0;
    }
}
```